# SQL - Improve pivot query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am performing a pivot operation in my stored procedure as follows, but its affecting the performance as i am using it for the report.

Is there any way/ substitute to this pivot operation to improve the performance? or can i apply indexes for this?

```
SELECT colId,colSequence,colDescription,
ISNULL([1],0) AS 'IESO',ISNULL([2],0) AS 'RFRC',ISNULL([3],0) AS 'EAL',ISNULL([4],0) AS 'HNS',ISNULL([5],0) AS 'PTE',ISNULL([6],0) AS 'EOC',ISNULL([7],0) AS 'MU'
FROM  
(  
 SELECT PF.FeatureId,PF.Sequence,PF.[Description],PTB.BenefitId,
 FROM PSP.table1 PF 
 LEFT JOIN PSP.table2 PTB  ON PF.FeatureId = PTB.FeatureId
 left JOIN PSP.table3 PO  ON PO.productID = PF.productId
 WHERE PF.ProductId = @ProductId  AND PF.IsDeleted = 0

) PS  
PIVOT  
(  
MAX (BenefitId)  
FOR BenefitId IN  
( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])  
) AS pvt  
ORDER BY colSequence
```

Comment: Why use PO in subquery? Its fields are not used in select

Comment: Post the execution plan. What are the `indexes` available in `table 1,2 & 3`

Comment: You can try running the SQL on this page, to see if you're missing any indexes (and if so, what impact they'd have on performance): http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/SQLServer/FindingMissingIndexes.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your query use `left JOIN PSP.table3 PO` but this table don't show in `SELECT` field list of subquery.

If this table is unuseful, you can remove it, so you'll gain an operation.

Check the indexes on your query tables, but I suppose you have on `FeatureId` an index as on `productID` field

Comment: There are possibilities that *filters* on `table3` table added dynamically through application code

Comment: @Prdp: but table3 is in LEFT JOIN, so he can't cut. Maybe he needs to increase row numbers, but we must wait the response of our OP

Comment: Agreed possibly it could increase the row count but practically that does not make any sense

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's super beneficial, but instead of PIVOT you can use aggregate case expressions to get the values you need.  you can use OUTER APPLY so you're not having to group by 3 columns, one being a description column.

```
SELECT  colId           = PF.FeatureId,
        colSequence     = PF.Sequence,
        colDescription  = PF.[Description],
        PTB.*
FROM    PSP.table1 PF
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  'IESO'  = COUNT(CASE WHEN BenefitId = 1 THEN 1 END),
                    'RFRC'  = COUNT(CASE WHEN BenefitId = 2 THEN 1 END),
                    'EAL'   = COUNT(CASE WHEN BenefitId = 3 THEN 1 END),
                    'HNS'   = COUNT(CASE WHEN BenefitId = 4 THEN 1 END),
                    'PTE'   = COUNT(CASE WHEN BenefitId = 5 THEN 1 END),
                    'EOC'   = COUNT(CASE WHEN BenefitId = 6 THEN 1 END),
                    'MU'    = COUNT(CASE WHEN BenefitId = 7 THEN 1 END)
            FROM    PSP.table2 PTB 
            WHERE   PF.FeatureId = PTB.FeatureId
        ) PTB
WHERE   PF.ProductId = @ProductId
        AND PF.IsDeleted = 0
```